# Table with fixed headers with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement a table with fixed headers using the concepts from this page:

http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html#

When I implemented the CSS from that page, my table columns are not aligned with the table headers.

HTML:

```
<div id="tableContainer" class="tableContainer">
    <table class="sortable" border=1 frame=void cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4>
        <thead class="fixedHeader">
            <tr>
                <th id="Column1" align=center valign=bottom>Column 1</th>
                <th id="Column2" align=center valign=bottom>Column 2</th>
                <th id="Column " align=center valign=bottom>Column 3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="scrollContent">
            <tr>
                <td align=right>ABCD</td>
                <td aligh=right>XY</td>
                <td aligh=right>12345678</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align=right>BAR</td>
                <td aligh=right>BAZ</td>
                <td aligh=right>12345678</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align=right>BAR</td>
                <td aligh=right>BAZ</td>
                <td aligh=right>12345678</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align=right>CD</td>
                <td aligh=right>FOO</td>
                <td aligh=right>12345678</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align=right>BAR</td>
                <td aligh=right>BAZ</td>
                <td aligh=right>12345678</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

CSS:

```
html>body tbody.scrollContent {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}
thead.fixedHeader tr {
    position: relative
}
html>body thead.fixedHeader tr {
    display: block
}
div.tableContainer {
    clear: both;
    border: 1px solid #963;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 300px
}
html>body div.tableContainer {
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.tableContainer table {
    float: left;
}
```

Here is that on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/softvar/yL84C/

I was able to 'fix' this by explicitly setting the cell size:

CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
th, td {
    width: 100px;
}

html>body tbody.scrollContent {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}
thead.fixedHeader tr {
    position: relative
}
html>body thead.fixedHeader tr {
    display: block
}
div.tableContainer {
    clear: both;
    border: 1px solid #963;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 300px
}
html>body div.tableContainer {
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.tableContainer table {
}
```

Here is that one jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cFr38/

But what I really want is the cells to be automagically sized based on the data (which is what my table does now without the new CSS)? How can I do that?

Comment: I'm using Table 'fixed header' CSS3 technique for many years (e.g.: http://webinfocentral.com/DigiCam.aspx#nav ), though the layout isn't quite "pixel-precise" :). Rgds,

Comment: Great, but how do I achieve what I want?

Comment: You have a lot of unnecessary code... why not just keep html>body tbody.scrollContent and div tableConatiner?

Comment: Ok, but how does your comment help me solve my problem?

Comment: I've posted a solution at: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/471756/Fixed-Table-Header-atop-scrollable-GridView-in-ASP You can take a look if you want. I will also add it to you post in a more formal way. Rgds,

Comment: The example you posted has set widths for the headers. To emulate it, you just need to explicitly set widths for the headers and then do the same for the columns.

Comment: @Alex W is right: headers columns width must be specified, either in absolute units, or %. This is essential part of the solution. Rgds,

Comment: Usually when I have a table I don't specify the widths and the cells are sizes for the max of each column. I want that behavior, but with the fixed headers. Is that possible?

Comment: Just to close out this thread, I ended up using http://nevcal.com/eclectic/UltimateScrollingTable.html